# Managed vs. unmanaged: how to marshal this

Tags: c#, dllimport, signature

I'm using a C++ dll containing a method with this signature:

```
int GetEnumerationString(int type, int value, const char** s ); /* ALLOCATES */
```

As mentioned in the header comment, the method allocates the pointer. I tried the following signature in C#:

```
[DllImport("thedll.dll", EntryPoint="GetEnumerationString")]
private static extern int GetEnumerationString(int type, int value, ref string s );
```

but when I run my program, I get an `AccessViolationException`.

What is the right signature for the method?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but have you tried dropping the 'ref' from your import sig?  'ref' indicates you're passing the string by reference, but trying to access a managed string from unmanaged code could well be giving you the AccessViolationException.

Comment: You may refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx) I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an unmanaged function allocates a buffer, it must use the CLR allocator in order for the CLR to pick up the memory and free it when needed.

If that is not possible, you must return a pointer:

```
[DllImport("thedll.dll", EntryPoint="GetEnumerationString")]
private static extern int GetEnumerationString(int type, int value, out IntPtr s);
```

Then manually [figure a string out of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe) and dispose the pointed to memory (for which you must know what the allocator was).